# Can you test a razor view on its own without the need for integration testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, integration-testing

I've got an MVC website with many different steps a user has to take to get through it. There are validation check and timed sections (for legal requirements). Having to do an integration test each time I need to test a small change to a page is a real headache. Ideally I want to know if there is a way (maybe a plugin?) that will allow me to right click a view, somehow specify a fake model object and open it directly?

What I am ultimately looking to test is how any new client side scripting (which combines razor/javascript/jQuery) looks and works on a variety of browsers. This isn't about testing functionality of my controllers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Design time data**

Design time data is commonly used in WPF, there is an article here that describes a techinque for showing design time data in MVC:

http://blog.dezfowler.com/2010/11/adding-design-mode-to-your-mvc-app.html

This should provide you a method to "somehow specify a fake model object and open it directly".

That might be all you're after, or:

**cURL**

Can be used with real time or design time data as above.

I use [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) executed from batch files and output the content to a number of files.

For example, this batch might simulate logging on:

**Logon.bat:**

```
echo Index without logon
curl http://localhost/index.html
echo Logon
curl http://localhost/login.html --data "username=a&password=p" ---dump-header auth.txt
echo Index after logon
curl http://localhost/index.html --cookie auth.txt
```

**RunAll.bat:**

```
call Logon.bat > logon_result.txt
```

The first time I run it, I also manually review the pages in a browser, then I know I can commit these batch result files (such as `logon_result.txt`) as the expected output.

Subsequent times I run the batch files, any changes are highlighted in revision control. At this point I review the differences and either OK them, and commit as the new expected output. Or I fix a bug.

I usually use this for WebAPI integration testing, but it should work for any http served page. One specific scenario to bare in mind is that for sweeping changes to a shared layout for example, you may not want to check them all manually. So make sure everything is checked and commited before the layout change, then little bugs won't be hidden within a vast number of changes.

I've caught some bad bugs with this techinque. Ever put an `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute` on a `ApiController` instead of an `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute`? Doesn't block unauthorized users, but code looks fine.

You may want to also set up a new clean database or restore a snapshot of one as the first task of the `RunAll.bat` file, so that any data displayed on pages is the same each run and doesn't show as a change.

Comment: Your design time data comes closer to what I want, but it is a fairly messy approach. I was hoping for something a bit more automated than this. So I've put a higher bounty out to see if anyone knows any more. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Testing a web application is a pretty big topic, but lets keep it simple:

To correctly test your application, you have to design the application in a way

- that all business logic can be tested via normal unit tests
- all data access can be abstracted and mocked
- data access can be integration tested separately

If you have a MVC website, you usually should have all business logic separated from any UI. This should actually enable you to use standard unit test projects to test lets say 80% of your code. Of cause you have to write a lot of code to test it right...

If you have tons of business logic in your view, this will result in very hard to test code.
The only way to do it (I know about) is automated UI testing. 
To do this, there are some useful frameworks available, also visual studio offers some tools to automate tests.

In general it works like this, you define actions you usually would do as a user in a web browser. All actions the user would do can potentially be tested by scripting it.
To do this, it highly depends on how complex and/or dynamic your UI actually is. The more fancy stuff you have, the harder it will get to write a test script...

Following are some great articles about automation testing:
http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2012/12/01/Automated-UI-Testing.aspx

http://blog.typemock.com/2012/05/22/automated-testing-of-asp-net-mvc-applications

here is also a quick video about how to get automated UI tests running in VS2012:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Visual-Studio-2012-Virtual-Launch/Automated-UI-testing-with-Visual-Studio-2012

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. The problem is I already do unit test my server side code and that works fine. This is much more about client side functionality which mixes both Razor syntax and Javascript/jQuery hence my need for something specific to these technologies.